# How to Validate appid of the Azure AD Access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt

We have a .NET Core application which performs JWT token authentication. This application is registered in Azure AD with a client Id of `abcde` and an API scope of `api://abcde`. Our tenant has other applications registered, one of which has a client id of `fghij`. What I noticed is that if I use this client Id with its secret and API scope `api://abcde` I was able to generate an access token and access the APIs under this scope.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"{ Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAD:Instance") }/{ Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAD:TenantId") }/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAD:Audience"),
        ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{ Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAD:TenantId") }"
    };
});
```

The solution I have in mind is to validate the appid field in the access token. How can I achieve this? Basically I want to make sure that only client Id `abcde` can request for an access token for scope `api://abcde`.

```
"aio": "abcde=",
"appid": "abcde", //client id of the application in Azure AD
"appidacr": "1",
```

Comment: I know this late response, you could build custom authentication handler and validate the token, https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/implementing-custom-authentication-scheme-and-handler-in-aspnet-core-3x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default Authorization policy to validate appid claim.
Out of the box, the default policy is:

```
new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
```

You can change it to:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("appid", "allowedApp1", "allowedApp2")
            .Build();
    });
```

Please see for reference [Setting global authorization policies using the DefaultPolicy and the FallbackPolicy in ASP.NET Core 3.x](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/)

Comment: Is it not possible to validate this in the `OnTokenValidating` event?

Answer (score 3):

You can get `ClaimsPrincipal` first and then use

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("appid").Value
```

to get the value of appid field. Then judge if the value equal to your specified app id.

Comment: Where should I use this? In the `OnTokenValidating` event?